# Cocoapods init for ios 7. How to update that?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Every time I type

```
pod init
```

the Podfile file comes with this for iOS 6

```
platform :ios, "6.0"
```

what do I have to do to make that command always generate for iOS 7

```
platform :ios, "7.0"
```

when I type `pod init`?  ... and preferably with that line uncommented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently [hardcoded](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/8a814f817d3d27e82c40d441f1a244c3b3765204/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb#L49-L65) into the `init` command. If you'd like to I'm sure you could submit a pull request for this to start the conversation about switching it.

Comment: great, thanks. I think init should check the project version instead of hardcoding it. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed. I know that this is possible and there was talk of that before. It might be worth bringing up again as well.